# WebStorm + nvm + Typescript + ts-node + Breakpoint Debugging - Randomly Stops Working

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm, nvm, ts-node

I have an issue with WebStorm that I can't seem to figure out and JetBrains hasn't been much help either.

It appears to sometimes show up, sometimes go away, and just flat out make zero sense. Debugging breakpoints in WebStorm will flat out stop working if they're inside of a non spec file function.

I'm using mocha, and my setup is as follows:

- nvm - using node 14.16.1
- mocha 9.02
- User interface: BDD

Env. Variables:

```
NODE_ENV=development;TS_NODE_FILES=true;TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true;TS_NODE_PROJECT=tsconfig.tests.json
```

Extra Mocha Options:

```
--require ts-node/register
```

Test file patterns:

```
src/tests/unit/**/*.ts
```

JetBrains had thought it was my code base, however, if I were to take and setup my other laptop with it, it breakpoints and works fine. However with WebStorm it randomly stops allowing me to breakpoint debug into nested functions...

I've tried uninstalling the nvm node version and reinstalling, wiped out `node_modules` and reinstalling, tried installing different node version and rebuilding `node_modules`. Nothing seems to resolve it.

One interesting piece, breakpoints work as expected when I don't run Spec files and run the app normally.

Comment: I forget how it works with WebStorm, are you able to see if a specific breakpoint is validated? e.g. what happens if you put a breakpoint on a blank line vs on a statement

Comment: can you attach code example and specify the line with the breaking point

Comment: @NaorTedgi It happens anywhere there is nested promise code. The bizarre part is debugging while not running tests works just fine. However, running unit tests it fails to break on the nested promises.